# JavaScript String Concatenation during Assignment

Tags: javascript

I am building a collection of buttons that are each going to be assigned to a variable. In my loop I have some id's that I want to append to each button's `id` attribute:

```js
var test = '<button id="myButton_" class="myButtonsClass" type="button">testButton</button>';
```

I want it to look like `button id="myButton_123"`.

Comment: What's your question? Are you looking for something like `var test = '<button id="myButton_' + idNumber + '" class="myButtonsClass" type="button">testButton</button>';`

Comment: Context?  What's your existing HTML?  Existing Javascript?

Comment: This is html built by JS

Comment: show us your loop please.

Comment: I think @neilsimp1 answer will work.....

Comment: If you're looking to just to concatenation, then yes. Looking at @Sampson's answer below, though, this is a much more proper way of handling this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid long strings, and use the methods provided to you by the DOM itself. Creating elements, and manipulating their content/attributes doesn't need to be difficult:

```js
// This will hold our buttons, so we aren't thrashing the DOM
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Lets cycle over a collection of ids
[ 23, 57, 92 ].forEach(function ( id ) {

    // Create a button, and get ready to manipulate it
    var button = document.createElement( "button" );

    // Set a few properties, and the content
    button.id = "myButton_" + id;
    button.textContent = "Test Button";
    button.className = "myButtonsClass";

    // Push this button into the fragment
    fragment.appendChild( button );    

});

// Now we touch the DOM once by adding the fragment
document.body.appendChild( fragment );
```

In modern ES6+ environments, you can use template literal strings for *in situe* interpolation:

```js
var id = "73868CB1848A216984DCA1B6B0EE37BC";
var button = `<button id='myButton${ id }'>Click Me</button>`;
```

That being said, I would still encourage you to break the task down into smaller, more consumable portions, and use the DOM apis to construct the element(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var template = '<button id="myButton_#" class="myButtonsClass" type="button">testButton</button>';

for (var i=0; i<10, i++) {
   console.log(template.replace('#',i));
}
```