# Common approach to prevent error during concatenation because of a `quote` symbol

Tags: javascript

I'm assembling an html tag as a string like this:

```
var tag = '<div some-attribute="' + attributeValue + '">';
```

The problem is that if `attributeValue` contains quotes `"`, the tag will be assembled with an error. What's the common approach to avoid such situation? I'm looking for a solution that accounts for all possible variations of a quote symbol.

Comment: The common approach is **avoid** using string concatenation to generate HTML. Use JS templates instead

Comment: `var tag = document.createElement('div'); tag.setAttribute("some-attribute",attributeValue); otherElement.appendChild(tag);`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, thanks, but what if the html string is huge and contains placeholders, and I can't control how it's created?

Comment: Well especially with a huge element, it is highly recommended to create a DOM object that you can directly apply your variables to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320217/2545680) explains that if attribute value is enclosed with double quotes, then only two characters are not valid within an attribute value:

> If your attribute value is quoted (starts and ends with double quotes
>   "), then any characters except for double quotes and ampersands are
>   allowed, which must be quoted as `&quot;` and `&amp;`

So I've replaced just these two characters and treat attribute value as safe afterwards:

```
var safe = attributeValue.replace("&", '&amp;').replace('"', '&quot;');
var tag = '<div some-attribute="' + safe + '">';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `encodeURIComponent` global method which will escape special characters from your string;

you will just have to decode it uppon accessing it with `decodeURIComponent`

```
var attributeValue = '"some'
var tag = '<div data-some-attribute="' + encodeURIComponent(attributeValue) + '">';
tag // "<div some-attribute="%22some">"
```

accessing it

```
var attribute = decodeURIComponent(div.getAttribute('data-some-attribute'));
attribute // "some
```

Comment: @Maximus again you will have to restore the values

Comment: yeah, if required, at the moment I'm not expecting users to put quotes or ampersands into attribute value

Comment: @Maximus you could also enforce correct formatting by stripping out those characters when they enter the value

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `"` *double quotes* in Javascript and contain within your string the `'` *single quotes* that will be understood by html. Or reverse.

You can also escape the quotes that you want to be in the string and not part of the separation by placing a `\` before them.

Your exemple would look like this:

```
var tag = "<div some-attribute=\"" + attributeValue + "\">";
```

But the **BEST SOLUTION** would be to dynamically create an objet that you would add the attributes to.

```
var tag = document.createElement('div'); // this creates a DOM div element
tag.setAttribute("some-attribute", attributeValue); // this changes the some-attribue to the value (could use with class)
containerElement.appendChild(tag); // this appends the newly created element as html in the container
```

I also suggest you check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699741/javascript-string-concatenation-during-assignment?rq=1) with a more complete response on how to create and append elements with Javascript.